# Is every tensor the gradient of a vector?

Tags: vectors, tensors, gradient-flows

I guess no, since every vector is not the gradient of a scalar - I assume ! Please confirm or guide in this regard .

Comment: What is your definition of tensor?

Comment: Is the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, as a tensor, a gradient?

Comment: What do you mean by the gradient of a vector? Do you mean the divergence/curl of a vector field or something like that? What is true is that not every vector field is the gradient field of a (potential) function (which I believe is what you mean when you say not every vector is the gradient of a scalar). I assume the space you are considering is $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n=2$ or $3$?

Comment: By tensor , I mean a 3 X 3 matrix, which we get in a voxel in 3D when we compute stress-strain tensor, or when we compute Diffusion Tensor in Diffusion Tensor Imaging.
The space Rn (sorry for this notation) as a reply to john is for n = 3 . 

Yes, I mean the vector field being the scalar of a gradient field. 

I misunderstood maybe, but I mean the Jacobian when we take the spatial gradient of each component of the velocity/vector field. I thought it is a tensor. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the second order tensor $\boldsymbol{T}$ whose matrix representation under the Cartesian basis $\{\boldsymbol{e}_{1},\boldsymbol{e}_{2}\}$ is 
$$\left[\boldsymbol{T}\right]=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
y & 0\\
0 & 0\end{array}\right).$$
Suppose $\boldsymbol{T}(x,y) = \nabla\boldsymbol{u}(x,y)$ for some vector field $\boldsymbol{u}(x,y)$. Do you see the issue?